# Desenvolvimento com Codename One

Tags: java, ios, api, codename-one

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento com o Codename One e por fim tenho uma dúvida sobre o suporte desta API com o desenvolvimento utilizando sockets.

Este pelo que pude perceber tem somente suporte ao desenvolvimento de sockets para TCP?

Answer (score 3):

> 08/01/2014 - At the moment we only support TCP sockets, we support server socket (listen/accept) on Android but not on iOS. You can check if Sockets are supported using the Socket.isSupported() and whether server sockets are supported using Socket.isServerSocketSupported().

Fonte: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2014/01/sockets-multiline-trees.html